# Avoiding null referencing in recursive datastructure in C#

Tags: c#, recursion, null

I am working with a `Binary` tree in C# and want to refactor the code, so none of the leafs in the tree is set to the `null` value.

Assuming we have the following class:

```c#
class Node
{
   int Data;
   Node Left;
   Node Right;
}
```

The classical constuctor for a node would be:

```c#
public Node(int Data)
{
  this.Data = Data;
  Left = null;
  Right = null;
}
```

But since I want to avoid null referencing, I wanted todo something similar to `string.Empty`, so my constructor would be something like:

```c#
public Node(int Data)
{
  this.Data = Data;
  Left = Node.Empty;
  Right = Node.Empty;
}


public Node()
{
  Data = int.MinValue;
  Left = Node.Empty;
  Right = Node.Empty;
}
```

I figured I could solve this by creating a `static readonly` variable called "Empty".

like so:

```c#
public static readonly Node Empty = new Node();
```

Tree traversal should in theory work, since instead of checking for if a leaf is equal to null, I would just have to check if a leaf is equal to the empty node, whichs means I would problaby also have to implement my own version of `Equals` right?

---

But I guess that would lead me in a bit of hot water, if I implemented the empty constructor like so:

The reason why I think it would land me into hot water, is that I believe the empty constructor would be called recursively.

If I set the leaf in the empty constructor alone to `null` I would get all kinds of warnings in Visual Studio, that a leaf might be null - even though it does never happen.

So what is the correct way if I want to avoid null referencing on a recursive data structure?

Comment: why not having null is a so important? is it that much of a difference comparing with null versus comparing with your Empty?

Comment: If you are dead set against making `Left` and `Right` nullable, your best bet is to just suppress the warnings in your `Empty` constructor.

Comment: In my datastructure - sure I could just keep it simple and use null - and tell the compiler I am aware of potential null reference and I have taken care of it. But lets say you have a WAY more advanced data structure. It might blow up - if you have not covered all cases. That is actually why Microsoft gives warnings when you are venturing into null referencing country. Hence it is good disciple to learn how to avoid null alltogether.

Comment: sure, so why are you trying hard to not have those warnings? Or is there another reason for this I cannot see?

Comment: I would just declare those nodes as nullable `Node? Left` and check for nulls, With nulls compiler will notice and complain that you did not check with your Empty property you are on your own.

Comment: 'avoid null alltogether'. I would strongly disagree. In my eyes, encapsulation is what you want. Hide the fields that can be null behind public accessors and methods that work correctly. e.g. `GetLeafNodes`would return Ènumerable.Empty`when its Leafs are null. But when you expose the internal data structure it sure is error prone and also hard to extend
So you probably spam your null checking hundreds of times in your code meaning you allready violated atleast 1 or 2 SOLID principles anyway.

Comment: @CSharpie I agree that the `GetLeafNodes` method is better than both approaches above, I was comparing having null to Empty property. In my opinion OP is choosing the worst option.

Comment: @Rafal I was refering to OPs last comment, yours was fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default constructor should be private and assign `this` to your nodes:

```
private Node()
{
  this.Data = int.MinValue;
  Left = this;
  Right = this;
}
```

its only purpose is to create instance for the Empty property:

```
public static readonly Node Empty {get;} = new Node();
```

this way if you will achieve what you want but this construction opens you for stack overflow exceptions when you fail to check your nodes for being Empty in contrast to having null there and having null reference exception. I would argue that those warnings, that you are trying to remove by providing a non null value always, are there to help your protect your code and, annoying as theory are, they are helpful in writing code with that null in mind.

Comment: Nice! I will try it out and see how Visual Studio handles it. I agree compiler warnings can be a bit annoying even though the warnings relates to a non-reachable state. But putting #pragma comments here and there to disable warnings is way ugly in my book. Hence I was looking for a way to make the compiler get to the conclusing "all variables is always instanciated" on its own, and thereby not showing any warnings.

Comment: ok, the unreachable state you mention is the circumstance I was missing for your approach to be valid. So if in your code you will never actually have to compare with Empty node that is fine. but you did mention an equals overload. So I'm not convinced :) by the way use `Object.ReferenceEquals` if you must.

Comment: Well it will have to compare with the empty node since all leafs in the bottom of the tree would point to the same instance of the empty node during tree traversal, but as long as all leaf points to the same object it would be manageable. Before you have to check if the leaf was null, so a bit of the same, but just different value to check for.